# Como desplazarme con las flechas del teclado dentro de una lista y seleccionarla con un enter

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una lista que muestra los datos de una base, la consulta es: como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda desplazarse sobre estos datos sin necesidad de utilizar el mouse para seleccionar una opción.
El código que estoy utilizando en Html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="contenedorselect">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="select-btn">
            <span>Selecciona</span>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-beat"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="search">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
              <input id="input-search" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
            </div>
            <ul class="options"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el js tengo el siguiente código:

```
let dataSelect;
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
selectBtn = wrapper.querySelector(".select-btn"),
searchInp = wrapper.querySelector("input"),
options = wrapper.querySelector(".options");

function getAgency(id){
    
    if(id!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"./recursos/ejecutar.php",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(info){
                $("#tabla_lista").css("display","block");
                $("#nombre_servidor").text(info.nombre_servidor);
                $("#ip_servidor").text(info.ip_servidor);
                $("#ip_tarjetas").text(info.ip_tarjetas);
                $("#usuario_tarjetas").text(info.usuario_tarjetas);
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        $("#tabla_lista").css("display","none");
        alert("Seleccione una agencia");
    }
}

function addAgency(selectedAgency) {
    options.innerHTML = "";
    dataSelect.forEach(agency => {
        let isSelected = agency == selectedAgency ? "selected" : "";
        let li = `<li onclick="updateName(this)" class="${isSelected}" data-id="${agency.id_agencia}">${agency.id_agencia}</li>`;
        options.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
    });
}
function updateName(selectedLi) {
    searchInp.value = "";
    addAgency(selectedLi.innerText);
    wrapper.classList.remove("active");
    selectBtn.firstElementChild.innerText = selectedLi.innerText;
    getAgency(selectedLi.dataset.id)
}

searchInp.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    let arr = [];
    let searchWord = searchInp.value.toLowerCase();
    arr = dataSelect.filter(data => {
        return data.id_agencia.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchWord);
    }).map(data => {
        let isSelected = data.id_agencia == selectBtn.firstElementChild.innerText ? "selected" : "";
        return `<li onclick="updateName(this)" class="${isSelected}" data-id="${data.id_agencia}">${data.id_agencia}</li>`;
    }).join("");
    options.innerHTML = arr ? arr : `<p style="margin-top: 10px;">Agencia no encontrada</p>`;
});

selectBtn.addEventListener("click", () => wrapper.classList.toggle("active"));
selectBtn.addEventListener("click", () => searchInp.focus());

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"./recursos/getAgencies.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(info){
            dataSelect = info ;
            addAgency();
        }
    })

    $("#tabla_lista").css("display","none");
    $("#listado").on('change', function(){
        var id=$("#listado").val();
        if(id!='')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"./recursos/ejecutar.php",
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function(info){
                    $("#tabla_lista").css("display","block");
                    $("#nombre_servidor").text(info.nombre_servidor);
                    $("#ip_servidor").text(info.ip_servidor);
                    $("#ip_tarjetas").text(info.ip_tarjetas);
                    $("#usuario_tarjetas").text(info.usuario_tarjetas);
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            $("#tabla_lista").css("display","none");
            alert("Seleccione una agencia");
        }
    })
})
```

y la hoja de estilo del código es esta:

```
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #4285f4;
}
.wrapper{
width: 310px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.contenedorselect{
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 0 0 126px;
}
.select-btn, li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-btn{
  height: 65px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.select-btn i{
  font-size: 19px;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}
.wrapper.active .select-btn i{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.content{
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position: absolute; /*linea para mostrar sobre las tablas*/
  z-index: 999; /*linea para mostrar sobre las tablas*/
}
.wrapper.active .content{
  display: block;
}
.content .search{
  position: relative;
}
.search i{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.search input{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 43px;
  border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
}
.search input:focus{
  padding-left: 42px;
  border: 2px solid #00BDD2;
}
.search input::placeholder{
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
.content .options{
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
.options::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 7px;
}
.options::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
  background: #b3b3b3;
}
.options li{
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.options li:hover, li.selected{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Estuve revisando un poco de información sobre Keypress, Keyup pero estoy un poco perdido en relacionarlo porque no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento, tal vez es algo muy sencillo pero soy novato sobre ese tema, gracias por su ayuda o guía.

Comment: No entiendo cómo fuiste a parar a esta implementación. Para empezar, lo único importante es poblar las opciones del dropdown, y en el testamento de código que pones es lo único que no haces. No será mejor llenar un `<select>` normal y embellecerlo con una librería como TomSelect o ChoicesJS ?